# Непонятный синтаксис в коде. @withRouter и тд?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Что значит @ в этом контексте кода? Не могу врубится. Скрин ниже

[image: скрин]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это декораторы: [ссылка](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-decorators/)

Например

```
@withRouter
class App extends ... {}
export default App
```

Эквивалентен записи

```
class App extends ... {}
export default withRouter(App)
```

Comment: А как экспортировать компонент вторым способом , если обёрток несколько? withRouter, connect и тд

Comment: export default withRouter(connect()(withStyles(styles)(App)))